# Setting up Google Pay API for Passes

Tags: google-pay

I've been following these instructions: 
https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/get-started/basic-setup/get-access-to-rest-api

In step

> 2. Select your account from the list. The Account Info page is displayed.

I can't find any accounts, 0 accounts is listed. If I try to create an account, I get an error message "Service account or user must be shared with an issuer."

Before that problematic step, I had done everything asked.

Have anyone of you done this before? Does anyone know how to contact Google with this matter? I've sent feedback to Google via website I provided earlier.

Comment: "Your Google Pay API for Passes account should have been created for you by your Google point of contact."

Comment: Yes, we got this working. It seems that there are big delay with account creation. In our case it took about two weeks.

Comment: Please wait until you account is created after submitting this form https://support.google.com/pay/merchants/contact/instore_merchant_interest?visit_id=637189488311884461-3625029917&rd=2.

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm not sure if Google create a account for me or not.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone who will meet this error:

Go to Pay&Wallet console and add your service account email in 'users' tab.

IDK why google dosen't add google pay API service accounts to Pay&Wallet console automaticaly. And why do we even need to add service account to console.